# How can I escape code in a Jade template filter, without single-quotes?

Tags: node.js, pug

I'm using the CoffeeScript filter in Jade on Node.js because I need to insert it into the contents of the script tag I'm generating. I can do this using:

```
:coffeescript
  myNum = '#{locals.myNum}'
```

On the server, locals.myNum is a number, but I have to quote the escape syntax so it ends up as a string on the browser. I can get around this with `parseInt` but there is probably a better way; something like `\#{locals.myNum}` would solve my problem but that doesn't work. Right now, I have to call parseInt everytime I put a server-side into my JS during template compile.

Is there a way to have Jade evaluate and output the contents of `#{}` *without* being in a single-quoted string, while compiling the template?

Comment: That does that same as `#{}` in single-quoted strings. The expression `!{}` won't compile at all, outside of some sort of quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a script block instead of :coffeescript and then reference it later in your :coffeescript block. Not the nicest, but an alternative to parseInt.

```
script
   myNum = #{locals.myNum}
```